# Converting concurrent_vector to std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, visual-studio-2013, ppl

I'm looking for the recommended way to convert a `concurrent_vector` from the PPL library to a normal std::vector.

I have a function which returns its results in a `std::vector` but may or may not use parallel algorithms internally. Currently I'm using `insert` to copy the elements from the concurrent vector to the normal vector:

```
#ifdef PARALLEL
    std::vector<Foo> Bar() {
        concurrency::concurrent_vector<Foo> cv;

        //Fill cv in a parallel algorithm

        std::vector<Foo> sv;
        sv.insert(sv.begin(), cv.begin(), cv.end());
        return sv;
    }
#else
    std::vector<Foo> Bar() {
        std::vector<Foo> sv;

        //Fill sv in a sequential algorithm

        return sv;
    }
#endif
```

Although the performance of the insert operation is not a real issu at the moment (compared to the function body), it just seems unnecessary and I wonder whether there is a better solution (Btw.: `Foo` is a simple POD which cannot be moved).

Ideally I would like to have something similar to this

```
std::vector<Foo> Bar() {
    concurrency::concurrent_vector<Foo> cv;

    //Fill cv in a parallel algorithm

    return static_cast<std::vector<Foo>>(cv);
}
```

or at least

```
std::vector<Foo> Bar() {
    concurrency::concurrent_vector<Foo> cv;

    //Fill cv in a parallel algorithm

    std::vector<Foo> sv(std::move(cv));
    return sv;
}
```

Are there any suggestions on how to do this properly?

---

EDIT:
As always I overlooked the most obvious simplification (suggested by Chris):

```
std::vector<Foo> Bar() {
    concurrency::concurrent_vector<Foo> cv;

    //Fill cv in a parallel algorithm

    return std::vector<Foo>(cv.begin(), cv.end());
}
```

while it (most probably) doesn't get rid of the copies it looks much cleaner.

EDIT2:

This leads me to the qestion of - assuming there is no way to explicitly prevent a copy of the vector data - how likely it is that the compiler can optimize the copy (from concurrent to std::vector) away, while still applying `RVO` or a move operation on the functions' return value

Comment: No need for `insert`. Use the constructor.

Comment: You can save a few lines by using `return {cv.begin(), cv.end()};` but I don't think there's any way other than copying.

Comment: I'd probably use `return {std::make_move_iterator(cv.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(cv.end())};`, although it obviously makes no difference if move is equivalent to copy for `Foo`.

Comment: @Chris: Good idea. While this doesn't prevent the copy, the code would look much cleaner that way

Comment: @Casey I was just typing [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5046e88d8e330048) up :) As you said, definitely the better option if `Foo` is moveable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> assuming there is no way to explicitly prevent a copy of the vector data - how likely it is that the compiler can optimize the copy (from concurrent to std::vector) away, while still applying RVO or a move operation on the functions' return value?

`concurrent_vector` is [quite different](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx#vector_differences) from `std::vector`. In particular, its data storage is not contiguous in memory, as `std::vector` requires. Thus the conversion you seek for is impossible, whether explicit or as a compiler optimization; data need to be copied from one location to another.

Comment: Thanks, I have to admit that I overlooked that "detail".

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to always use `std::vector` with parallel algorithms.

Algorithms and containers are normally independent / orthogonal, so you can use, for example the standard algorithms in [Parallel Mode with g++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/libstdc++/manual/manual/parallel_mode.html), same applies to [TBB algorithms](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unless I missunderstand something, I believe this doesn't apply to my situation. The "parallel algorithm" is a `parallel_for_each`, where - depending on the the result of the loop body - items may or may not be appended to the vector. Of course I could guard the vector access manually with a mutex, but I believe the usage of a thread safe container makes the code less error prone, so I would like to stick to `concurrent_vector`. This has also the advantage, that the loop bodies of the parallel and sequential version can be absolute identical.

Comment: @MikeMB I see. In this case you could append the results to different vectors (one for each thread) and merge the vectors at the end in the calling thread. That could be even faster because the worker threads would not contend on appending to the same vector, however, your loop would probably have to be different for parallel and non-parallel versions.